# SSIS remove $ format from csv

Tags: excel, ssis, ssms, etl

I have a csv file with multiple columns that are formatted as currency, what is the best way to remove the formatting but keeping the values. I would like to automate the process if possible.

[image]

I tried using the data conversion tool but I must be doing something wrong.

This is what the raw file looks like in NotePad. :

```
1-2-1,2020,1,1,Ada,2,County,1,Ada County," $144,552,433 ",," $27,710 "," $57,836 ",0.00,,,,,,," $12,251,223
```

Excel Snip
[image: x]

Comment: by definition, a CSV file contains only text, not formatting. Your screenshot clearly shows an Excel format applied to a cell. What is the actual corresponding entry when you open the CSV file with a text editor? How did you treat the CSV file, so it shows in Excel? That process will determine how the cell displays. I suggest you look into Power Query (Get & Transform) to load the CSV file and clean it up before it gets loaded into the worksheet grid.

Comment: The file is originally an Excel workbook, I take each sheet and convert them to CSV then import them to SSIS. Even after saving as CSV the file retains the currency data type.

Comment: This is what the raw file looks like in NotePad. :    1-2-1,2020,1,1,Ada,2,County,1,Ada County," $144,552,433 ",," $27,710 "," $57,836 ",0.00,,,,,,," $12,251,223

Comment: Your sample in the comment is most helpful. I clicked the Edit button to add it into the actual question as comments are ephemeral. What would really improve things would be to show us the row that contains your screenshot of the interpreted value of "$  416,512,510"

Comment: I added a screen shot for the NotePad text example @billinkc

Comment: So, do you want to open the filel in Excel or in SSIS? The screenshots are Excel and I posted an answer to that issue below. I don't know about SSIS.

Comment: I need to convert the excel file into a flat file then load into SSIS. There are multiple sheets and would like to automate this. I think my the best option is using derived column transformation

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Derived Column and apply REPLACE SSIS expression for the currency column to remove $

```
REPLACE(ColumnName,'$','')
```

Then map the output to destination column.

Answer (score 0):

The raw data clearly shows the currency fields as text, with a $ character included and surrounded by blanks. If you open this CSV file with Excel, Excel will do some built-in interpretation of the values and translate a text containing a $ sign and numbers into a numeric value that it formats as a currency in the Excel grid. The underlying value of that Excel file is still a number.

If you want to avoid that, load the data via Get&Transform on the Data ribbon, and clean up the data in Power Query before you load it into the Excel grid.